# Backbone Collection adding empty object when API returns no data

Tags: api, backbone.js, backbone.js-collections

I have the following problem: My API returns null - no data available. (that's good!). My `collection` gets the data but creates one single empty object.

**My API result (from Firebug):**

```
{"data":{"objects":null}}
```

**My collection:**

```
var MyCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: MyModel,
    url: '/v1/ajax/load-objects',

    parse: function(resp, xhr) {
        return resp.data.objects;
    }
});
```

When I print `self.model.toJSON()` in my view (the model is the collection), I get this (by Firebug):

```
 [Object {}]
```

My question: Why is the collection putting one empty bject in my collection? The API returns null, so it should be empty.

I tried adding default values to my model (which the collection uses), they are not shown. So I guess it's taking the null as the data for one object. How can I stop him doing this?

Thx

Ron

Comment: Have you tried returning an empty array (`[]`) when `objects` is null? IIRC Backbone expects an array to be returned from `parse`. I'd guess it sees you returning a single object (null) and assumes you wanted a one-element long array.

Comment: good point, I'll give it a try

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you poke around Backbone's source code, you'll see that models inside a collection are handled by [`Collection.set`](http://backbonejs.org/docs/backbone.html#section-111)

Once `Collection.set` has parsed your data, it performs a check on what you actually returned and creates an array if the value (`null` in your case)  is not an array :

```
var singular = !_.isArray(models);
models = singular ? [models] : models.slice();
```

This list of models is then processed and creates a single model in your collection.

The solution is simple : return an empty array when you hit a `null` value in `parse` :

```
var MyCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: MyModel,
    url: '/v1/ajax/load-objects',

    parse: function(resp, xhr) {
        return resp.data.objects || [];
    }
});
```

And a demo simulating your problem http://jsfiddle.net/nikoshr/s2dve9ob/ and its solution : http://jsfiddle.net/nikoshr/s2dve9ob/1/

Answer (score 0):

Ok, now it seems to work. But I really don't get why :)

I added (empty) `defaults` to my model. Now it works.

```
var MyModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
    defaults: {
    },

    initialize: function () {
        var self = this;
    }
});
```